# Till what age will an infant keep waking to nurse each 3 hours?

Tags: infant, sleep, newborn, breastfeeding

I have twin boys who are 6 weeks old. They breastfeed each 3 hours as an average. However this is making me tired especially during the night. Till what age will they keep waking each 3 hours?
Is there anything I could do to make them sleep longer durations during nights?

Comment: based on our experience, 1y5m and still going... :)

Comment: Just saying... 1 year and still waking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not just one answer to that question, because it varies by the child and the situation.  Could be 2-3 months, could be much longer (easily could be 6mo+).

There's also a second issue with your question: 'waking up to nurse' versus 'waking up hungry'.   If they're waking up actually hungry, then you need to feed them (or find a solution to feeding them in some other fashion).  If they're not actually hungry, they may just want to nurse because they like the feeling and the attention.  Kids will very often do that for quite a long time, and you need to learn to differentiate waking from real hunger and waking just because they want mommy - and deal with them differently.

The most general answer to your question is that for kids that are 'bad' at waking up, often when they start consuming a significant quantity of solid foods (usually around 5-6 months), they begin to sleep better at night.  That's not a suggestion to start solids early, as that's not necessarily good for their development, but more of a 'this is when it may happen'.

You may want to consider pumping if you're not already doing so, and having your husband or another caretaker responsible for some middle of the night feedings, perhaps every few days so you're able to get more regular sleep.

Comment: A lot of people don't have extra milk for pumping: do not feel bad about giving formula during the night. Have your husband take one feeding. Especially with twins.

Comment: While I certainly agree no one should feel bad about needing to use formula for any reason, regular pumping in addition to feeding increases production, not decreasing it.

Comment: I don't know any woman who liked to pump, and found it 'easy' to do on top of regular feedings. I found myself already exhausted enough, and so did just about everyone else I know who tried.

Comment: Not sure what that has to do with supply, which was the part of your comment I was disagreeing with.

Comment: actually no formula is used. but I am pumping and giving bottles.

Comment: Sounds like its time for daddy to pitch in at night then (spoken as a daddy who enjoyed doing so from time to time!)

Comment: they are waking up hungry... as I stopped the habit of waking up to nurse which started to be all day and night and I am exhausted enough. so I used the pacifier instead.

Comment: Daddy always handles one boy while I handle the other. but still I need to supervise.

Comment: If the pacifier works, they are not hungry.  That's one of the better signs actually. Pacifier makes them feel good but doesn't remove the hunger sensation if it exists.

Comment: After time passes... it took them nearly 1y 8mo to sleep through the night, although twinB kept waking from time to time to nurse, until he was weaned on 2yrs